# A-Frame / THREE.js, Simplify modifier on gltf[glb] models

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

One of the examples in three simplify modifier found here
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/modifiers/SimplifyModifier.js

I understand it takes in a geometry, and simplifies it.

is there a way to do this with a gltf model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes — refer to the [simplifier example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=implif#webgl_modifier_simplifier) for full code, but the gist is that you can use SimplifyModifier as usual, except that you need to traverse the model in case it contains multiple meshes:

```js
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load( 'foo.glb', function ( gltf ) {

  const model = gltf.scene;
  const modifer = new THREE.SimplifyModifier();

  model.traverse( function ( o ) {
  
    if ( o.isMesh ) {

      const numVertices = o.geometry.attributes.position.count;
      o.geometry = modifer.modify( o.geometry, Math.floor( numVertices * 0.9375 ) );

    }

  } );

  scene.add( model );

}, undefined, function ( e ) {

      console.error( e );

} );
```

Comment: That did the trick!, although im now having an issue with the texture's associated with the model, I opened up a new post for organization here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102935/a-frame-three-js-no-textures-simplified-gltfglb-models