# A-Frame / THREE.js, no textures simplified gltf[glb] models

Tags: three.js, textures, uv-mapping, gltf

After simplifying glb successfully with the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087673/a-frame-three-js-simplify-modifier-on-gltfglb-models).

The textures in are not being applied to the model any more (it appears completely black and unreflective(no material)

How would I programmatically get the textures to work with this new simplified geometry?

I think its something to do with the uv's but im not to sure how to have it work according to simplified geometry, if even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`THREE.SimplifyModifier` currently does not preserve UVs in the geometry, which you'll need for textures to work. See: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14058. There is a workaround suggested in that issue (via changes to SimplifyModifier) but as discussed there, some artifacts will likely be visible in the result. If you can do the simplification in Blender or another modeling tool, you may have more control over the process and can get better results.